# Adding an attribute to a link that's been matched with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to add tracking code to any `<a>` tags whose `href` property ends with `.pdf`. The tracking code is an `onClick` property, `onClick="LogClick(this);"`. So, an example link may go from `<a class="some-class" href="/path/to/some/file.pdf">` to `<a class="some-class" href="/path/to/some/file.pdf" onClick="LogClick(this);">`.

I believe I have a regular expression that will match for those tags, but I'm having trouble understanding what to do from here. This is being done via PHP, I feel like the function `str_replace()` may be useful, but I'm not sure how to keep the contents of the string and only tack on a bit after the `href`.

My regular expression:

```
<a (.*)?href=('|")(.*).pdf('|")(.*)>
```

Comment: Try [like this using `preg_replace`](https://eval.in/585529). You can [test regexes here](https://regex101.com/r/sX2lG3/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this,

```
<?php
$html = '<a class="some-class" href="/path/to/some/file.pdf">';
echo preg_replace('/(<a (.*)?href=(\'|")(.*).pdf\3(.*?))>/', '$1onClick="LogClick(this);">', $html);
```

`str_replace` won't work with regular expressions. I used a back reference in the regex as well so whatever quote type was used on the opening href matches the closing. You also might want to consider using a parser.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/585526
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sZ0qE0/1